# Access VBA - Query Parent Table Data Easily?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Is there a shortcut way to access fields in a parent table in my query like the below:

```
SELECT childField1
FROM childTable
WHERE childField2 = "somestring"
AND
WHERE parentField1 = "someotherstring" 'parent field is in parentTable
```

My tables are of course keyed correctly with ID fields and a `parentField1_ID` in the childTable.

I can go the traditional route with some `JOIN`s, but given that this is VBA i'm wondering if there isn't something easier built in to make this kind of reference.

Comment: *given that this is VBA*...I do not see any VBA code, only an SQL query. What is the context you need to run (i.e., form recordsource, combo rowsources, DAO recordsets)?

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you build a dynamic query string that results in the SQL string required (including joins, or whatever else you need), then you typically use `currentDb.OpenRecordset()` to set a recordset variable.  Alternatively, the string can be applied to form and control Recordsource properties.

Here's an (non-working - your joins requirements are clear to me) example using variables for your two strings:

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim sql As String

str1 = "somestring"
str2 = "someotherstring"

sql = "SELECT childField1 " & _
      "FROM childTable1 " & _
      "INNER JOIN parentTable " & _
      "ON childTable.childField = parentTable.ParentField " & _
      "WHERE childField = """ & str1 & """ AND " & _
      "  parentField = """ & str2 & """;"

Me.RecordSource = sql
```